# How to Rotate an Object and Reset it's Rotation to Zero?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

The problem for the turnover is that the axis is attached to the geometry.

Now: http://f2.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhEy.png

Now (rotate): http://f3.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhEC.png

Necessary (rotate): http://f1.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhEG.png

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 180 * 90;
```

*sets* the rotation, it does not *increment* it.

In three.js, an object's orientation can be specified by its Euler rotation vector `object.rotation`. The three components of the rotation vector represent the rotation in radians around the object's internal x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis respectively.

The order in which the rotations are performed is specified by `object.rotation.order`. The default order is 'XYZ' -- rotation around the x-axis occurs first, then the y-axis, then the z-axis.

Rotations are performed with respect to the object's *internal* coordinate system -- not the world coordinate system. This is important. So, for example, after the x-rotation occurs, the object's y- and z- axes will generally no longer be aligned with the world axes. Rotations specified in this way are not unique.

For more information about Euler angles, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). Three.js follows the Tait–Bryan convention, as explained in the article.

EDIT: If you want to "reset" the rotation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27023024/1461008).

three.js r.73

Comment: You do not understand the essence. Need to fix this rotation, something to be followed with respect to zero.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding your English, and what your problem is. I added some more information to the post. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thank you! It works! . eulerOrder = 'ZYX';But the question is still open. How can we apply the figure of a turn and lose a turn on zero? To be able to rotate the shape as you like for whatever you like after the rotation axis without binding. Sorry for the English, Google translator, I am Russian (

Comment: Draw this problem... [http://f2.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhDA.png](http://f2.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhDA.png)

Comment: Oh! A picture is worth a thousand words. :-) You cannot reset the rotation to zero. However, you can move each point in your original geometry: geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY( radians ) ); It is not very efficient, though. ---- When you are happy with my answer, I will correct the English in your question and post a  correct answer. You can then "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(...) == mesh.rotation. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate or otherwise transform an object, but then treat it as non-transformed for the purposes of further transformation, one approach is to add it to a new Object3D instance and apply the additional transforms to that:

```
var line = new THREE.Geometry();

line.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ),
);

line.rotation.z = 30 * Math.PI / 180;

var lineObject = new THREE.Object3D();
lineObject.Add(line);
// lineObject.rotation.z == 0 and its rotation axes align with the world
// you can perform any further rotations on lineObject
```

You can learn more about this transform-stacking approach from this video from the Udacity ThreeJS course:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBemS5NCVyw

The lecturer discusses how to rotate a clock's hand after it has been rotated,
 compared to ThreeJS' native rotate-then-translate behavior (so he's stacking a translation on a rotation, while you're performing two independent rotations, but the idea is the same).

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this with Points? I can't get it to work yet...

Comment: Ah, given a mesh of Points named `mesh` one can do `mesh = new THREE.Points(mesh.geometry, material)`