# threejs rotation by x and z works individually but fails together

Tags: three.js, webgl

I need to rotate the diamonds (see attachement) around the x and z axis. When rotating individually (meaning I only set rotation.x or rotation.z) the rotation looks fine and it works. But when I set both the rotations (x AND z) the rotation looks like this:

[image: diamond rotation fail]

Do I miss something? Is somehow the object local coordinate system rotated and now rotation around 2 axes fail?

```
diamond.position = brilliantPositions[i][0];
diamond.rotation = brilliantPositions[i][1];
this.frames.arrangementMesh.add(diamond);
```

Thanks in advance for a hint
Kind regards
Roman and Patrick

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774633/how-to-rotate-an-object-and-reset-its-rotation-to-zero/14776900#14776900) answer for an explanation of Euler rotations in three.js r.58.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The euler order indeed solved the problem for us. In our case we had to do the follwing

```
diamond.eulerOrder = 'ZYX';
```

in order to have the calculation take the right way. Many thanks!

[Here's more information about euler order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774633/how-to-rotate-an-object-and-reset-its-rotation-to-zero/14776900#14776900)

PS: I couldn't accept the comment as answer WestLangley therefore I just upped it and reposted the solution here

Comment: And now I can accept my own answer in 8 hours oO this stuff is very weird... I'll be back in 8 hours then

Comment: These days it was renamed though. I think rotation.order is the new property

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using lookAt() function and then applying rotation around one of the axis. That should be good enough for almost any kind of rotation in space.