# Three.js - Can I 'apply' position, rotation, and scale to the geometry?

Tags: three.js, geometry, transformation

I'd like to edit an object's position, rotation, and scale vectors, then 'apply' them to the geometry, which would zero-out those vectors, but retain the transformation.

For example, let's say I import a cube with a side-length of 1. The min and max vertices of the cube are located at `(0, 0, 0)` and `(1, 1, 1)`. I set the object's scale to `(2, 2, 2)` and then apply the transformation to the geometry.

After applying, the scale is reset to `(1, 1, 1)` and the min and max vertices of the cube are `(0, 0, 0)` and `(2, 2, 2)`, respectively.

Is there some built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can apply an object's transform to the object's geometry directly, and then reset the position, rotation, and scale like so:

```
object.updateMatrix();

object.geometry.applyMatrix4( object.matrix );

object.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
object.rotation.set( 0, 0, 0 );
object.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
object.updateMatrix();
```

three.js r.150

Comment: How do I do it for a THREE.Group() which can in turn contain THREE.Group()?

Comment: @AmriteshAnand You will need to make a new post and show your code if you have a question.

Comment: Is this still correct for modern three.js? When I try do this on a Mesh instance, it just resets everything back to way it was before I rotated anything. I should note that I substituted applyMatrix with applyMatrix4 as applyMatrix no longer seems to exist

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a wrapper object, where the child object will have the default rotation, position and scale:

```
const ChildObject = load(/*...*/);
ChildObject.rotation.set(90, 0, 0); // default rotation goes here
const MainObject = new THREE.Object3D();
MainObject.add(ChildObject);
```