# How to apply a matrix transformation and set the result as default state in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js

I have a group of THREE.Mesh objects. My goal is to use something like
 `group.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( Math.PI / 2) );`. Then, I would like to make the result as the group default matrix, so that I can use matrixUpdate() in my animation.

In ThreeJS docs, we can find: "Calling updateMatrix will clobber the manual changes made to the matrix, recalculating the matrix from position, scale, and so on."

Is there a way to make the manual changes I want and then set the result as if it was the default state of group?

Comment: create another Object3D on top of your structure and set the matrix there.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022160/three-js-can-i-apply-position-rotation-and-scale-to-the-geometry/27023024#27023024

Comment: @WestLangley In my case, I have a group of THREE.Mesh, not only one. How can I adapt for my case?

Comment: @gaitat As I said, I do already have an Object3D on top of my structure, called "group".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @WestLangley related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022160/three-js-can-i-apply-position-rotation-and-scale-to-the-geometry/27023024#27023024), here is the solution for my problem! After executing all the matrix transformations I want, I just needed to do:

```
group.children.forEach( function(mesh) {
    mesh.geometry.applyMatrix( group.matrix );
});
group.updateMatrix();
```

Comment: This is updating the vertices of the geometry. Maybe what you want, instead, is `mesh.applyMatrix( group.matrix );`.

Comment: @WestLangley I needed to update the geometry for my purposes... In this case, I wanted to correct the rotation of an object made of a group of meshes