# Apply transformation to the matrix and reset values on Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, transformation

I'm having an issue with my 3D manipulation application. I'm using the THREE.JS. What I'm trying to do is change the scale of one object, apply this transformation to the original matrix and then restore the values of scale to 1.

I need to restore the transformation because some functions used by the UI are using this information. So, basicaly I want to considere this new size as the original size, without any transformations.

Is there any way to do that? I did some research but none of the answers has solved my issue.

```
var scale = 0.5; 
object.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022160/three-js-can-i-apply-position-rotation-and-scale-to-the-geometry/27023024#27023024

Comment: @FastSnail Actually it changes the scale of the object, but what I want to do is set this new size as the original size, making the Scale value = 1

Comment: @WestLangley applyMatrix is undefined for me :(

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27023024/3866399

Fixed with this, but I hade to change:

```
object.geometry.applyMatrix( object.matrix );
```

to

```
insertedPrintable.object.children[0].geometry.applyMatrix(cloneMatrix);
```

Comment: This answer is not useful to others without knowledge of your source code. Apparently, your question is missing important, and relevant, information.