# Is it possible to apply rotation/scale/position on THREE.Object3D

Tags: three.js, transformation

Using blender Im used to apply any transformations to object with CTRL+A; so object becomes zero transformations (rotation/scale/position). Then I can transform object from scratch not worring about previous transformations.
Is there any way to do the same in THREE.JS? Something like THREE.Object3D.commitTransforms()?
[blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zclHK.gif)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022160/three-js-can-i-apply-position-rotation-and-scale-to-the-geometry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the intended effect by using [BufferGeometry.applyMatrix()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.applyMatrix) and passing the `Object3D.matrixWorld` into it. This will bake the world transformation into the geometry.

However, you have to manually reset `Object3D.position`, `Object3D.scale` and `Object3D.rotation`.

`three.js R109`.