# Three.js - rotating an Object3D around an axis

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

I'm trying to rotate a mesh loaded into an `Object3D` using `OBJMTLLoader`.

```
var obj = new THREE.Object3D();
// loading and stuff

obj.rotation.y += 0.1; //inside the update function
```

This works as it should, but only for y and z axes. Using the same code, but for the x axis yields the same result as rotating it around the z axis, but clockwise instead of counterclockwise.

Unfortunately, I need to rotate it around the x axis.

```
var xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
obj.rotateOnAxis( xAxis, 0.1 );
```

This does rotate the object around the x axis.

However, I want to tween the rotation of the object, so I need a way to explicitly change the angle an object is rotated by, instead of rotating it for a specific amount.

Any ideas why `obj.rotation.y` and `obj.rotation.z` work properly, but `obj.rotation.x` doesn't?

Comment: putting a live example up e.g. as a jsfiddle would help greatly in figuring this out. sound very strange so far but is probably something simple.

Comment: @antont thanks, but I figured it out.

Comment: thanks for sharing the solution, makes sense now and I'm glad that learned how such a situation can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon loading the mesh (before trying to rotate it around the x axis), I rotated it by 90 degrees around the y axis. Because of the default Euler order (which is `XYZ`), the local axes no longer corresponded to the world axes.

```
obj.eulerOrder = 'YXZ';
```

Using the above line of code before rotating the mesh around the y axis solved the problem.

A pretty good explanation of Euler order can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774633/how-to-rotate-an-object-and-reset-its-rotation-to-zero/14776900#14776900).